# How to find a repeated sequence of numbers in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

suppose I have the next data frame and what I want to do is to identify and remove certain observations.

The idea is to delete those observations with 4 or more similar numbers.

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c(12,34,233,3333,3333333,333333,555555,543,456,87,4,111111,1111111111,22,222,2222,22222,9111111,912,8688888888))

         col1
1          12
2          34
3         233
4        3333
5     3333333
6      333333
7      555555
8         543
9         456
10         87
11          4
12     111111
13 1111111111
14         22
15        222
16       2222
17      22222
18    9111111
19        912
20 8688888888
```

So the final output should be:

```
   col1
1    12
2    34
3   233
4   543
5   456
6    87
7     4
8    22
9   222
10  912
```

Comment: Point of clarification: should 155155 be included or excluded?

Comment: should be included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of removing the desired values would be to directly filter `1111`, `2222` etc., using `grep()` after converting the numbers to characters.

```
df$col1[-as.numeric(grep(paste(1111*(1:9), collapse="|"), as.character(df$col1), value=F))]
# [1]  12  34 233 543 456  87   4  22 222 912
```

Comment: Build a regex. Good call. Note that `grep` has an invert argument which could be used in place of the `-`. Also, `grepl` is a natural replacement here.

Comment: For fun, here's an alternative: `df$col1[!grepl(paste0((1:9), "{4}", collapse="|"), as.character(df$col1))]`.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most efficient method, but it seems to return the desired result. Convert the vector into a string, split each individual character, use `rle` to look for repeating sequences, take the maximum and return TRUE if that max is less than 4.

```
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$col1), ""),
          function(x) max(rle(x)$lengths) < 4), , drop=FALSE]
   col1
1    12
2    34
3   233
8   543
9   456
10   87
11    4
14   22
15  222
19  912
```

This method will include values like 155155 but exclude values like 555511 or 155551.

Comment: Why not simple `table` instead of `rle`?

Comment: I guess it depends on if the OP wants total number of a digit or repeated sequences (for example 155155). I went with the latter, but `table` (or `tabulate`) would work better for the former interpretation.